# What happens to the bonuses when I build a city in a special resource tile?

Tags: civilization-5

Does the city destroy the resource?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you have the relevant technology to access the resource normally (eg, you need Calendar to build a plantation on a hex containing wine to gain access to the resource) then building a city on the source will instantly grant you the resource.

If you *do not* have the tech when you build the city then it is not destroyed, it will just be granted to you when you unlock the required technology.

In my current game (I'm alt-tabbed as I type) I have a city built on spice generating 2 food, 2 hammers and 3 gold - not the usual 1 gold, and according to the help spice grants +2 gold on it's tile. So it seems actually you *do* retain the output bonus from the resource.

And, you do lose the ability to build the relevant special construction on top of the tile for an extra production bonus (eg, you can't build a plantation on the city hex, even if it's placed on top of a wine resource, so won't get the extra tile bonus you would normally get from building a plantation).

Comment: In Civ V at least, all city tiles ignore resources when determining base output. a city established on a grasslands is just the same as a city established on a cow -- but if someone has evidence that contradicts me, then by all means, share, for I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks @Raven, as said this was something I was unsure of, I'm quite happy to take your word for it as I did have an uneasy feeling it was wrong. I'll adjust the answer and as Raven has said - anyone with evidence to the contrary please come forward!

Comment: @Raven I retract my agreement, as per my last edit, I've a city on top of spice generating 3 gold, not 1, as per the +2 bonus for spice. So I think the tile output bonus *is* retained.

Comment: Does Food / Production get modified as well or *just* gold production? (sounds like time for !!Science!!)

Comment: @Raven I didn't think to check that... but I did stick another city on Dyes for another +2 gold there as well!

Comment: I built a city on top of cotton and it didn't retained the gold output bonus

Comment: @Jader - did you have the technology to access Cotton at that stage in the game? If not, did you gain the bonus at the stage where you did have the tech?

Comment: @DMA57361 I think Cotton requires Calendar. And I had Calendar.

Comment: All my cities tiles have the same output regardless of the terrain. Just the tiles around the cities that vary.

Comment: @Jader - I wonder if there's been a change in a patch or if we'd just reached the wrong conclusion in the original discussion... hmm...

Comment: @RavenDreamer It's not as simple as resource bonuses being ignored. First resources (and bonuses from buildings, religion, etc.) are applied to the tile. Then the two-production one-food minimum is applied to the tile. Resources (and resource + building or resource + religion or resource + technology) bonuses that exceed that minimum are not lost, those that are below that minimum are lost. I go over the consequences in detail in [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115442/what-bonuses-do-i-get-from-the-tile-on-which-i-place-my-city/115446#115446).